# Text substitution with specific fields in a log file.

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cut

I have this:

```
00:05:40.005 id=32214483 Src=PIPE <abc@example.com> (received) To=xyz@example.com relayed (1234 bytes)
```

I need to achieve this:

```
00:05:40.005 id=32214483 Src=abc@example.com <abc@example.com> (received) To=xyz@example.com relayed (1234 bytes)
```

NOTE - I can't swap the data "by column" and apply that to the entire file as I have other data in the file that has the correct format I need. I simply wish to swap out all instances of Src=PIPE with the data in the next column without the <> symbols.

Comment: something like this? `echo '00:05:40.005 id=32214483 Src=PIPE <abc@example.com> (received)' | sed -E 's/Src=PIPE <([^>]+)/Src=\1 <\1/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the perl one liner will do what you what:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/Src=PIPE\s+<(\w+?@\w+?\.\w+?)>\s+?/Src=$1 <$1> /;' [file(s)]
```

Another way that doesn't check to make sure the element in the angle brackets is an email address:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/Src=PIPE\s+<(.*?)>\s+?/Src=$1 <$1> /;' [file(s)]
```

The -i.bak makes a backup of each of the files processed on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this:**

```
$ sed 's/PIPE <\(.*\)>/\1 <\1>/g' -i file.txt
```